# Check if value exists in random n-dimensional array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am writing a function that checks if a n-dimensional array has a certain value:

```
function checkVal(array, value) {
  if (value exists) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

My problem is that I want this function to work for any array regardless of its number of dimensions or types of elements. I tried to first flatten the array, but only managed to do it for a couple of dimensions.

EDIT: 
Some examples of possible arrays:

```
var arr1 = ['1','3',['a','b'],'4,5'];

var arr2 = ['a','b',['c','d',['e',['e',['e',['e',['e',['e',['e',['e',['e',['e',['f',['f',['f',['f',['f',['f',['g',['g',['g',['g',['g',['g',['g',['h']]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]];
```

Comment: Please add some cases of arrays...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to flatten the array, that's just extra work. What you need is a recursive function:

```
function checkVal(array, value) {
    // `Array#some` loops through the array until the iterator
    // function returns true; it returns true if the iterator
    // does at some point, false otherwise
    return array.some(function(entry) {
        // If this entry in the array is an array, recurse
        if (Array.isArray(entry)) {
            return checkVal(entry, value);
        }

        // It isn't, do an equality check
        return entry === value;
    });
}
```

`Array#some` and `Array.isArray` are both ES5 functions, so present in any modern browser, and both can be shimmed/polyfilled for older ones like IE8. Or, of course, the above can be rewritten with a boring `for` loop and the old `Object.prototype.toString.call(entry) === "[object Array]"` test for whether something is an array.

Note that I've used `===` for the equality check. If you need something more complicated, like object equivalence rather than identity, etc., make the change there.

Example/basic tests:

```js
function checkVal(array, value) {
  // `Array#some` loops through the array until the iterator
  // function returns true; it returns true if the iterator
  // does at some point, false otherwise
  return array.some(function(entry) {
    // If this entry in the array is an array, recurse
    if (Array.isArray(entry)) {
      return checkVal(entry, value);
    }

    // It isn't, do an equality check
    return entry === value;
  });
}

snippet.log(checkVal(['a', 'b', 'c'], 'b'));         // true
snippet.log(checkVal(['a', 'b', 'c'], 'd'));         // false

snippet.log(checkVal([['a'], ['b', 'c']], 'c'));     // true
snippet.log(checkVal([['a'], ['b', 'c']], 'd'));     // false

snippet.log(checkVal([['a'], [['b', ['c']]]], 'c')); // true
snippet.log(checkVal([['a'], [['b', ['c']]]], 'd')); // false
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a recursive function to check in all child of your array

```
function searchValue(arr, val){
  // found another array
  if(arr instanceof Array){
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
      if(searchValue(arr[i],val)){
        return true; // stop on first valid result
      }
    }
    return false;
  }else{
    // found a leaf
    return arr == val; // <-- if you want strict check, use ===
  }
}

if(searchValue(myArray, 'my variable')){
  // do something..
}
```

it works in any browsers